# Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) driver fail

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

Installed latest 18.04 on an old HP G7000 laptop and having issues with slow graphics response due to a driver fail.

Below is a probe of the HW:

https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=e3648286fe

I am aware that there was a fix-all website for Intel drivers (01.og) but it does not provide an installable tool currently.

Also, there used to be a bug during boot concerning SVIDEO but it was fixed by modifying the GRUB (video=SVIDEO-1:d). All I have left is this frustrating driver.

Anything I can do? Thank you so much for answering.

Answer (score 1):

After many unsuccessful tries, just upgraded to Xubuntu 19.10. Now everything works like a charm.

Stay away from the buggy 18.04!

New config: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=cb550f69f7